# Получить разрешение facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Здравствуйте!

У меня вопрос по поводу Facebook API.
Есть приложение через которое будет происходить постинг сообщений только на страницу компании.
Нужно получить разрешение на `business_management`, `manage_pages`, `publish_pages`.

Вопрос в том  как это сделать?

Так как администрировать приложение будет 1 человек, но постинг сообщений будет происходить по некоторому событию на сайте, и доступа к нему другим пользователям не будет, но по правилам нужно предоставить кнопку входа Facebook и добавить скринкаст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение нашел.
Нужно быть администратором приложения и создателем странички что бы свободно добавлять новости на страничку.

Для администратора получение разрешений не требуется.
Для работы с приложением рекомендую создать `long-live token`.

Как это сделать читаем здесь: [Как сделать токен](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426018/generate-never-expire-access-token-for-facebook-page)